# Angular - How can I test a container component with a custom input component child?

Tags: angular, forms, unit-testing

### Problem

I have a container component that uses a custom input component. It works fine while serving or after building, but, it doesn't work on tests.

This is the error I'm getting:
`Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'name'`

---

### Here is a simplified version of my files:

#### Template

```html
<app-modal>
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
    <app-input formControlName="name"></app-input>
  </form>
</app-modal>
```

#### Test

```js
@Component({ selector: 'app-input', template: '' })
class InputStubComponent {}

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    declarations: [
      InputStubComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      ReactiveFormsModule,
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

---

I've also tried: using `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and not declaring the component.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of solving this:

**RECOMMENDED**
1) You can remove the `ReactiveFormsModule` from the `imports` property, and add the `FormBuilder` to the `providers` property. The `ReactiveFormsModule` adds `formGroup` and `formControlName` directives, which do checks on a template level.

This is how it would look like in your example:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    declarations: [
      InputStubComponent
    ],
    providers: [
      FormBuilder
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

---

2) If you want to test your child component, or to keep the `ReactiveFormsModule`, here is a function that creates a barebones stub component with value accessor:

```js
const createAccessorComponent = (selector) => {
  @Component({
    selector: selector,
    template: '',
    providers: [
      {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => AccessorComponent),
        multi: true,
      },
    ],
  })
  class AccessorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    writeValue(obj: any): void {}
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {}
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}
    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {}
  }

  return AccessorComponent;
};
```

You can use it in this way:

```js
const InputStubComponent = createAccessorComponent('app-input');

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    declarations: [
      InputStubComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      ReactiveFormsModule,
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```